# How to parse json to object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I want to create an object with one field: List

```
public class Responce {

List<String> cities 

// some methods

}
```

JSON itself looks like this (it has an object in the object) :

```
{"responce" : {
   "list" : {
    "1": "А",
    "2": "B",
    "3": "C",
      .....  
    }
  }
```

I just want to get List of A, B, C and all of this without creation tons of classes:)

I have tried JsonNons and @JsonPropery, but no luck so far.

Comment: your problem statement is not very clear. The json you have shared does not match your object. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean put only values (A,B,C...) into List<String> cities

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question much but if you need to deserialize the json data then you can try this.

Create a pojo class for List

```
public class cityListPojo{

   private List<String> cityList;

   public List<String> getCityList() {
       return cityList;
   }

   public void setCityList(List<String> cityList) {
       this.cityList = cityList;
   }
}
```

Then using jackson library you can convert your json string that you are receiving to cityListPojo class Object as

// jsonString:- Get the json from db or where-ever you are getting and convert it to string.

```
cityListPojo obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, cityListPojo.class);
```

Then use obj object to get the List back as.

```
List<String> cityList = obj.getCityList();
```

// Use these jackson dependencies just for reference.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set cities like below,

Response.java

```
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, String> list;

    @JsonIgnore
    List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();

    public Map<String, String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(Map<String, String> list) {
        Set<String> keys = list.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            cities.add(list.get(key));
        }
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(List<String> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

Test method

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = " {\r\n" + 
                "   \"list\" : {\r\n" + 
                "    \"1\": \"А\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"2\": \"B\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"3\": \"C\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"4\":\"D\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"5\":\"E\"\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "  }";

        Response response = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);

        System.out.println("Object:" + mapper.writeValueAsString(response));

        System.out.println("Cities:");
        for (String city : response.getCities()) {
            System.out.print("\t" + city);
        }
    }
```

**OR** Can use Custom Serializer

Response.java

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ResponseSerializer.class)
public class Response {

    private Map<String, String> list;

    List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();

    public Map<String, String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(Map<String, String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(List<String> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

ResponseSerializer.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class ResponseSerializer extends StdSerializer<Response> {

    public ResponseSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ResponseSerializer(Class<Response> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Response value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();

        Map<String, String> list = value.getList();

        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> keys = list.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            cities.add(list.get(key));
        }
        jgen.writeObjectField("cities", cities);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Test Method

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
        Response response1=new Response() ;

        Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();

        map.put("1", "A");      
        map.put("2", "B");
        map.put("3", "C");

        response1.setList(map);

        System.out.println("Object:" +  mapper1.writeValueAsString(response1));

        System.out.println("Cities:");
        for (String city : response1.getCities()) {
            System.out.print("\t" + city);
        }
    }
```